# Read 3dpdf annotation view

Tags: pdf, itext, acrobat-sdk, u3d

Can anyone help me out to **read the 3dpdf all 3D annotation view**, with out open the 3dpdf document through C#.
Through ITextSharp I am able to place annotation view but able to read the same.

Comment: You want to extract data from an existing PDF, more specifically: you want to extract something from a `/RichMedia` annotation that contains U3D (not that U3D is being replaced by PRC). The question is: what do you mean when you say "able to read the same." It isn't clear what you want to achieve? What is "reading the 3D annotation view"? PDF annotations don't exist outside a PDF.

Comment: @bruno the OP is probably from India, and in Indian English they use "the same" to refer to a previously mentioned item. It's very ambiguous language for anyone outside the Indian subcontinent. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30000/using-the-expression-the-same-for-a-previously-mentioned-item

Comment: @ Bruno..I do have one 3dpdf and I want to extract its data through C#. I am generating 3DPDF from one of the application and to verify 3DPDF I am not able to get any API or any code to extract whole data of 3dpdf.